# How to convert time stamp to epoch/nanoseconds in Java?

Tags: java, time

I have a `Date` value of `Tue Mar 27 17:57:35 PDT 2018`, and I'm trying to convert it to nano/epoch time format. I've tried

```
Date ts = data.get("timestamp").getTime()
Instant ts = data.get("timestamp").toInstant()
```

But none of these work. I've searched extensively and can't seem to find an example that allows me to to convert this format to epoch.

Comment: If all you've got is time to second-precision, you can only convert it to a timestamp with second-precision. I mean, you can then multiply it by 1e9; but you're not gaining any precision by that.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.time.Instant;

// getCurrent DateTime in Epoch till NanoSecond
public String getCurrentTimeInEpochInNanoSecond(){
   Instant instant = Instant.now();
   return "" + instant.getEpochSecond() + instant.getNano();
}
```

Output:

> 1629453692809644400

When you convert TimeStamp to HumanDate, that is

> GMT: Friday, August 20, 2021 10:01:32.809 AM

The return type of the method is `String` because it will overflow in `long`.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is "nano/epoch format"? Is just the numerical value for the number of nanoseconds since unix epoch?

If that's the case, you can convert the `java.util.Date` to `Instant` using `toInstant()` method, and then get the numerical values from it:

```
Instant instant = date.toInstant();
long secondsSinceEpoch = instant.getEpochSecond();
int nanoSeconds = instant.getNano();
```

Unfortunately, the total number of nanoseconds will be too big to fit in a `long`, so you need to get in 2 separate fields (as above): the number of seconds since epoch, and the nanoseconds value (9 fractional digits).

Just reminding that `Date` has millisecond precision (only 3 fractional digits),   so there's no way to get nanosecond precision with it.

Comment: To be precise, the long type can fit the nano seconds until `2262-04-11T23:47:16.854Z`, so it would be still safe to use until then.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the example below after importing `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;`

```
String target = "2018/03/27 17:57:35 AM";  // Your given date string
long nanoseconds = ...;   // nanoseconds since target time that you want to convert to java.util.Date

long millis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(nanoseconds, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS); 

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm aaa");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = formatter.parse(target);

long newTimeInmillis = date.getTime() + millis;

Date date2 = new Date(newTimeInmillis);

System.out.println(date2);
```