# Convert date time string to nanoseconds since epoch in Java

Tags: java, date, time

I'm trying to convert date time string like 25-05-2022 05:40:51 to nanoseconds (1653457251000000000) since epoch in Java

Comment: In which time zone is that date and time?

Comment: Did you try your search engine? Does this answer your question? [How to convert time stamp to epoch/nanoseconds in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565223/how-to-convert-time-stamp-to-epoch-nanoseconds-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to calculate the nanos (as already mentioned in [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20689298/1712135)), there seems to be no possibility of directly deriving that value from an `Instant` or any equivalent class in `java.time`. You will have to explicitly provide a time zone (`java.time.ZoneId`) if you want a reliable solution that does not depend on the configuration of the JVM the code is executed on.

Steps you can perform:

- define a formatter and use it to parse the `String`, which should result in a `LocalDateTime` because your input does not contain a time zone or offset
- provide the time zone and use it together with the `LocalDateTime` producing a `ZonedDateTime`
- get the `Instant` defined by the `ZonedDateTime` and use its epoch millis value in order to calculate the nanos

Here's a demo that shows you how a time zone matters in your case:
Different ones are likely to produce different values, so better explicitly define one in your code (long version for readability).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define the expected nano value
    long expectedNanos = 1653457251000000000L;
    // your example input (no time zone or offset given!)
    String input = "25-05-2022 05:40:51";
    // create a formatter to be used as parser for the input
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss");
    // parse it to have a LocalDateTime
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, dtf);
    // create two zones in order to find out how the zones matter here
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    ZoneId kolkata = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    // apply each zone to the LocalDateTime and create two ZonedDateTimes
    ZonedDateTime timeInUtc = localDateTime.atZone(utc);
    ZonedDateTime timeInKolkata = localDateTime.atZone(kolkata);
    // Instants can be derived from ZonedDateTimes, do so twice here        
    Instant utcInstant = timeInUtc.toInstant();
    Instant kolkataInstant = timeInKolkata.toInstant();
    // provide a factor for a full nano calculation
    long nanoFactor = 1000000L;
    // calculate the nanos
    long nanosInUtc = utcInstant.toEpochMilli() * nanoFactor + utcInstant.getNano();
    long nanosInKolkata = kolkataInstant.toEpochMilli() * nanoFactor + kolkataInstant.getNano();
    // produce some meaningful output (expected value or not?)
    String utcOutput = String.format("UTC:     %-40s ––> %d  => %s",
            timeInUtc, nanosInUtc,
            (expectedNanos == nanosInUtc) ? "expected" : "unexpected");
    String kolkataOutput = String.format("Kolkata: %-40s ––> %d  => %s",
            timeInKolkata, nanosInKolkata,
            (expectedNanos == nanosInKolkata) ? "expected" : "unexpected");
    // and actually print that output
    System.out.println(utcOutput);
    System.out.println(kolkataOutput);
}
```

This will result in the following lines pointing out the importance of the time zone:

```
UTC:     2022-05-25T05:40:51Z[UTC]                ––> 1653457251000000000  => expected
Kolkata: 2022-05-25T05:40:51+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]  ––> 1653437451000000000  => unexpected
```

As you can see, the time of day as well as the date is the same (in your input and both output values), but the offset from UTC is different (*Z* is an offset of `00:00` hours). That will of course result in different `Instant`s.

Given your expected result, you should provide UTC as zone.

Comment: Good answer with good explanation and good awareness of time zone. Thanks. For calculating the nanos I think I’d be lazy and just do `ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(Instant.EPOCH, timeInUtc)`. Since java.time already knows how to convert `timeInUtc` to an `Instant`, this works. `between()` also detects `long` overflow.

Comment: *Given your expected result, you should provide UTC as zone.* Given the expected result it *is* also possible, though unlikely, that the OP intended Africa/Ouagadougou, America/Danmarkshavn, Atlantic/Reykjavik, Atlantic/Azores or some other time zone. Most likely you are correct, and the OP knows best.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use any online Java Compiler like Programiz to test this

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String sDate6 = "25-05-2022 05:40:51";   
        SimpleDateFormat formatter6=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
            Date date6=formatter6.parse(sDate6);
        System.out.println("Hello" + date6 ); 
        Instant instant = date6.toInstant();
        System.out.println("\n seconds: " + instant.getEpochSecond());
        System.out.println("\n remaining ns: " + instant.getNano());
        System.out.println("\n ns since epoch: " +(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(instant.getEpochSecond()) + instant.getNano()));
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use SimpleDateFormat to turn convert it to an Instant? Why not use DateTimeFormatter directly?

Comment: Seriously, please don't mix those two APIs, either stick to `java.time` or use the outdated `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`…

Comment: Wait… Is this actually an answer or your code effort that should have been in your question?

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. Since you are using java.time, also use its `DateTimeFormatter` class for parsing.